# Need help with the famous 11 second intercom audio from Mega Man Legends 2

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dJxBnRth-A&t=1m40s

Need 日本語字幕 subtitles for this short 11 second announcement heard in the background. I've listened to this for over a decade, and could never understand what the intercom voice is saying in japanese.

1:40-1:51

「ウェルナー・フォン・ミュラーさま･･･」

「ウェルナー・フォン・ミュラーさま･･･」

**(ち きゅう/急)**中門ホールまでお越しください。

間のなく、**(りはたり/記者会議)**を開始いたします。

Over Intercom:

Mr. Verner Von Bluecher! Mr. Verner Von Bluecher!

Please report to the Central Hall!

The press conference is about to begin.

Answer (score 2):

至急、間もなく、リハーサル. The rest seems right (though I can’t quite make out the word before ホール myself. It sounds more like 入門... **EDIT**: per @naruto’s comment, it is indeed likely 中央.)

Comment: @ Darius Jahandarie Thanks in advance! That was lightning quick! I posted a similar question like this on reddit and no answer all day. I wonder what happened to reddit/translator? They used to be so fast, then, after this summer, it seems like the admins/helpers all got lazy and just stare at the posts, but don't bother to lift a finger to help.

Comment: yw! We usually don’t accept transcription questions here but you seemingly put quite a bit of effort into this, so :)

Comment: 「中央ホール」のような気がします